# Getting process id without library functions?

Tags: c++, c, process, pid

Hi I know how to get the pid using c++ using library function getpid() is there anyway to do this without calling a library function?

Comment: What are you expecting, a language feature?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `getpid()`?

Comment: You can directly write assembly code, but the details are OS and architecture dependent.

Comment: I would like to use syscall but couldn't find good documentation on it

Comment: You should explain why you don't want to use [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html). I see no reason to avoid using it.

Comment: Have you also considered doing a `ls /proc/self/task/` or a readdir() on `/proc/self/task/`, which should return the pid of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're after syscall then there is this:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = syscall(SYS_getpid);

    std::cout << pid << '\n';
}
```

Comment: But there is no reason to code this way, which is probably slower than calling [getpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html) because of [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

For my windows buddies out there..

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>

int getPID()
{
    #ifndef _MSC_VER
        #ifndef __x86_64__
        asm ("movl %%FS:0x20, %%eax":::);
        #else
        asm ("movq %%GS:0x40, %%rax":::);
        #endif
    #else
        #ifndef _WIN64
        __asm {mov eax, FS:[0x20];};
        #else
        __asm {mov rax, GS[0x40];};
        #endif
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", getPID());
    printf("%d", GetCurrentProcessId());
}
```